# only one editor at a time? RCP

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I was wondering if there is a manner to make it impossible to open more than 1 editor at a time? what I have now is a button that each time it is pressed gives a new editor.
I am using eclipse RCP

thanks

Comment: Why are you using an editor? - Doesn't make a ViewPart which is refreshed on clicking on the button much more sense at all? - What happens if the editor is dirty, what if the editor contains invalid values?

Answer (score 1):

You could add an `IPartListener` on the `IPartService` of the `IWorkbenchWindow` that close all other editors when a new editor is opened. You find the current set of editors via `IWorkbenchPage.getEditorReferences()`.

Comment: Assuming that there is always only one editor open, IWorkbenchPage.getActiveEditor() should be enough ;)

Comment: @Tom Well, the problem is that you only get notified _after_ the new editor is opened and then `IWorkbenchPage.getActiveEditor()` will return the new editor and not the old editor. Anyway, I usually prefer algorithms that have as few pre-conditions as possible - even if it is a little more complex... :-)

Comment: you're right. My comment was misleading, getActiveEditor must be called **before** opening the new editor. Anyways, probably the easiest would be IWorkbenchPage.closeAllEditors(save) before opening a new one :)

Comment: Agree... The problem is just how to do that. AFAIK, there are no hook or listener for just that :-(

Comment: @Tom Ohh, I agree about the use of views rather than editors. Any day!